# Calculate percentage group by outputs incorrect results

Tags: sql, group-by, clickhouse

I'm trying to get percentage from the table in clickhouse DB. I'm having a difficulty writing a query that will calculate percentage of type within each timestamp group.

```
SELECT
    (intDiv(toUInt32(toDateTime(atime)), 120) * 120) * 1000 AS timestamp,
    if(dateDiff('second', toDateTime(t1.atime), toDateTime(t2.unixdsn)) <= 5, 'sec5', if((dateDiff('second', toDateTime(t1.atime), toDateTime(t2.unixdsn)) > 5) AND (dateDiff('second', toDateTime(t1.atime), toDateTime(t2.unixdsn)) <= 30), 'sec30', if((dateDiff('second', toDateTime(t1.atime), toDateTime(t2.unixdsn)) > 30) AND (dateDiff('second', toDateTime(t1.atime), toDateTime(t2.unixdsn)) <= 60), 'sec60', 'secgt60'))) AS type,
    count() AS total_count,
    (total_count * 100) / 
    (
        SELECT count()
        FROM sess_logs.logs_view
        WHERE (status IN (0, 1)) AND (toDateTime(atime) >= toDateTime(1621410625)) AND (toDateTime(atime) <= toDateTime(1621421425))
    ) AS percentage_cnt
FROM sess_logs.logs_view AS t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        trid,
        atime,
        unixdsn,
        status
    FROM sess_logs.logs_view
    WHERE (status = 1) AND (toDate(date) >= toDate(1621410625)) AND if('all' = 'all', 1, userid = 
    (
        SELECT userid
        FROM sess_logs.user_details
        WHERE (username != 'all') AND (username = 'all')
    ))
) AS t2 ON t1.trid = t2.trid
WHERE (t1.status = 0) AND (t2.status = 1) AND ((toDate(atime) >= toDate(1621410625)) AND (toDate(atime) <= toDate(1621421425))) AND (toDateTime(atime) >= toDateTime(1621410625)) AND (toDateTime(atime) <= toDateTime(1621421425)) AND if('all' = 'all', 1, userid = 
(
    SELECT userid
    FROM sess_logs.user_details
    WHERE (username != 'all') AND (username = 'all')
))
GROUP BY
    timestamp,
    type
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

**Output**

```
┌─────timestamp─┬─type────┬─total_count─┬─────────percentage_cnt─┐
│ 1621410600000 │ sec5    │       15190 │     0.9650982602181922 │
│ 1621410600000 │ sec30   │        1525 │    0.09689103665785011 │
│ 1621410600000 │ sec60   │          33 │   0.002096658498169871 │
│ 1621410600000 │ secgt60 │          61 │  0.0038756414663140043 │
│ 1621410720000 │ secgt60 │          67 │   0.004256852102344891 │
│ 1621410720000 │ sec30   │        2082 │    0.13228009070271735 │
│ 1621410720000 │ sec60   │          65 │   0.004129781890334595 │
│ 1621410720000 │ sec5    │       20101 │     1.2771191658094723 │
│ 1621410840000 │ sec30   │        4598 │    0.29213441741166873 │
│ 1621410840000 │ sec60   │          36 │   0.002287263816185314 │
│ 1621410840000 │ secgt60 │          61 │  0.0038756414663140043 │
│ 1621410840000 │ sec5    │       17709 │     1.1251431922451591 │
│ 1621410960000 │ sec60   │          17 │  0.0010800968020875095 │
│ 1621410960000 │ secgt60 │          81 │   0.005146343586416957 │
│ 1621410960000 │ sec30   │        2057 │    0.13069171305258864 │
│ 1621410960000 │ sec5    │       18989 │      1.206468127931748 │
│ 1621411080000 │ sec60   │           9 │  0.0005718159540463285 │
│ 1621411080000 │ sec30   │        3292 │    0.20915756896894594 │
│ 1621411080000 │ sec5    │       15276 │     0.9705622793346349 │
│ 1621411080000 │ secgt60 │          78 │   0.004955738268401514 │
└───────────────┴─────────┴─────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

It is returning the percentage for each row, but when I do sum of percentage_cnt column, the total does not goes to 100% instead it goes to 80%.
Please help me in correcting my query. I know query is huge, you guys can give simpler example for my use case. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get what this query is calculating. Clickhouse does not support correlated sub-queries, it's unclear why do you use a constant as a divider.

Comment: Table engine is MergeTree which supports sub-queries.

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/6697#issuecomment-525739426

Comment: correlated sub-queries are not supported. Subquery != correlated sub-query